# CakePHP 3 create dynamic Menu

Tags: php, cakephp, menu

I am trying to create a short submenu for CakePHP with a Database Table.

First I tried this solution [how to create dynamic navigation menu cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386031/how-to-create-dynamic-navigation-menu-cakephp) which seemed outdated (because its two years old) and since I don´d need to add menus over the add function, its to big anyways.

So can I solve this with just the table in my DB, the model in Cake and an element?

Thats what I got so far:

**src/template/element/main.ctp**

```
<ul class="header main-menu">
    foreach($something as $something ) :
        ?>
        <li>
 somethine
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**my view**

```
<?= $this->element('main'); ?>
```

**My Model**

```
class Menu extends Entity
{

    var $name = 'Menu';

}
```

Is this the way to go?

Comment: which version of cakephp? In cake3 you can use cells to retrieve your data from DB

Comment: @arilia it is cake3

Answer (score 1):

your question is a little generic, but here's something you want to consider:[Html helper class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html)

and in particular [Html helper lists](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-nested-lists). That way you can do in your main.ctp:

```
    $list = [];
    foreach ($menu as $menuItem) {
    $list[] = $menuItem;
}
   echo $this->Html->nestedList($list);
```

Comment: I am getting this error tho Notice (8): Undefined variable: menu [APP/Template/Element/main.ctp, line 4] - seem I can´t get the right data in my main.ctp